# one click publishing a web application without restarting it

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, msdeploy

I have installed Web Deployment service on a Windows 2008 machine, started using one click publishing in VS2010 and it works.

With one glitch, even though I change a view only file (like a *.cshtml razor file which is not compiled), web site is restarted. Therefore user sessions are lost.
Maybe I am missing something so trivial, because it knows uploading only the changes.

Does anyone know whether restarting can be prevented using one click publishing or not?
If not, suggestions are welcome ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Any time the web.config file or any binary file is changed, the application will be restarted.  Likely you are uploading the web.config file, even though it's not technically changed, IIS sees the file has been written to so it considers that a change.

I'm not really familiar with the web deployment service, so I'm not sure if it's possible to avoid uploading certain files (ie. the web.config file) or not.  But one alternate solution is to move your sessions to a SQL server, which will allow them to survive application restart.  (Granted, this might be overkill)

Comment: I do not think config files are sent anyway, unless there is an issue with config xml transforms being executed regardless of any change.

Comment: I need the session, just to avoid DB every time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that you are using InProc as your SessionMode.

I suggest you read something about the topic SessionMode in the MSDN and evaluate which SessionMode is your way to go. (I think the easiest, besides InProc, would be StateServer)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, indeed a local state server would solve the user session issue. Yet, the real problem is the web site being restarted which is not necessary.

Comment: @orca: Sure that you areusing a Web Application Project and not a Web Site Project? Like Coding Gorril said, changing anything that is not the web.config or a binary should not effect recompiling.

Comment: isn't it the opposite? Nevertheless, this is a web application project and I usually need to change a few lines of javascript inside a view.